# Typo3 Neos HTML to PDF

Tags: pdf, typo3, tcpdf, fpdf, neoscms

I got problem when trying to create PDF file. Is there any other way to create pdf beside using FPDF? Because i'm struggling to include the class from fpdf into the backend.

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/fpdf17/fpdf.php');
$pdf = new \Backend\Controller\fpdf17\FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
```

But this code is not working, got problem with the require.

And i also try with TCPDF but it's not working.

The error for TCPDF is i'm stuck on TCPDF Examples page.

This is the code https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d346ff2d6fb9d1852925

Anyhelp would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer

when trying to call the TCPDF class :

use this :

$pdf = new \TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

instead of :

$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);